# How to draw pixels in color red on the image in pictureBox1 in real time on mouse move event?

Tags: c#, winforms

i'm trying to draw pixels in red color while moving the mouse so where the mouse cursor is inside the pictureBox1 draw at that point a pixel.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            pictureBox1.Image = Properties.Resources._image;
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
           
        }

        private void pictureBox1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            label1.Text = String.Format("X: {0}; Y: {1}", e.X, e.Y);

            Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(pictureBox1.Image);

            for(int x = 0; x < bmp.Width; x++)
            {
                for(int y = 0; y < bmp.Height; y++)
                {
                    bmp.SetPixel(e.X, e.Y, Color.Red);
                }
            }

            bmp.Dispose();
        }
```

this is very slow and not drawing pixels in red.

Answer (score 0):

This is working in the mouse move event :

```
private void pictureBox1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            label1.Text = String.Format("X: {0}; Y: {1}", e.X, e.Y);
            Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(pictureBox1.Image);
            bmp.SetPixel(e.X, e.Y, Color.Red);
            pictureBox1.Image = bmp;
        }
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).